# More detail on the '-g' option in npm

Tags: npm

I often see in tutorials on on SO that `npm install -g` and according to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), "In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package."

What exactly is a "global package"?

Answer (score 0):

I found this at http://browsenpm.org/help#globalPackageInstallation

> The -g flag will indicate that http-server should be installed
>   globally, and be available for all node scripts to require.
>
> Now, we can require [package installed with '-g'] in any node script on our system.
>
> In addition, since the http-server package has specified a bin
>   property, it will also install a binary script called http-server
>   globally.

Answer (score 0):

Installing as a global package means, that you can run it from every directory.

If its not globally intalled, you can only run it from the directory it is installed in and you always have to navigate to that directory to run it, or add it to your `PATH` variable.

It is way more convenient to install globally for most purposes